# Proof Problem Rudin PMA 1-4

Tags: real-analysis

Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* Chapter 1 #4

Let *E* be a nonempty subset of an ordered set; suppose $\alpha$  is a lower bound of *E* and $\beta$ is an upper bound of *E*. Prove $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Attempt:

Let *E* be a nonempty subset of an ordered set S.
Suppose $\alpha$ is a lower bound of *E*.
Suppose $\beta$ is an upper bound of *E*.
If $\gamma \gt \alpha$, $\gamma$ is not a lower bound of *E*.
Hence $\alpha \leq x$ for all x$\in$ *E*. Therefore $\alpha \in$ *E*.
If $\gamma \lt \beta$, then $\gamma$ is not an upper bound of *E*.
Hence $x\leq \beta$ for all x$\in$ *E*. Therfore $\beta \in$ *E*.
So $\alpha \leq x \leq \beta$ for all x$\in$ *E*.

Perhaps my approach is flawed but I'm not sure how to go from this to $\alpha \leq \beta$.

Comment: If γ>α, γ is not a lower bound of E. - This is false. $\gamma$ is not $\inf$, just a lower bound.

Comment: do you mean $\alpha$ instead of $\gamma$ in your second sentence?

Comment: Yes, sorry for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overthinking this. Since $E$ is nonempty, there is some $x\in E$. Since $\alpha$ is a lower bound for $E$, $\alpha\leqslant x$. Since $\beta$ is an upper bound for $E$, $x\leqslant\beta$. Hence by transitivity,
$$\alpha\leqslant\beta. $$

Comment: I have that statement. Are you saying that $\alpha \leq x \leq \beta$ is equivalent to $\alpha \leq \beta$?

Comment: I wasn't precise with my answer; since $\alpha\leqslant x$ and $x\leqslant \beta$ and $\leqslant$ is transitive, it follows that $\alpha\leqslant\beta$. See definition 1.5 in the text.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for help.